# Does Vision have AI capabilities like Ultron?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe

As seen in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Ultron had all the abilities of an AI. Going into the internet, absorbing all of human history, creating "copies" of himself in other robot bodies, etc. Why hasn't Vision been shown to also have any of these abilities?

He has been shown to be able to "interface?" with technology, when he "hacked" Ultron and locked him out of the internet, but has never shown any abilities like this afterwards. So does he or doesn't he have any AI type capabilities? I don't see why Vision wouldn't have these same abilities as Ultron did.

Comment: Good question.  I'm thinking maybe he could, but can't remember having seen a situation where he needed to do those things.  Do you have an example scenario where these skills would have come in handy?

Comment: Asking whether he has abilities is fine but your question also includes another question "Shouldn't Vision have..." which will lead to answers which are opinions, speculations instead of facts or references. Such questions get closed.  You should remove that portion from the question.

Comment: @binarymax I mean for one, if he could "go into the internet" or "copy" himself, in *Infinity War*, Shuri wouldn't have had to try pulling his consciousness out of the Mind Stone. He was only wounded and weak because Corvus Glaive stabbed him with the Glave. But if he could "copy" himself to the internet, he wouldn't have been in any real danger, because it was only his body that was damaged.

Comment: Unless, as being stabbed by the Glave disrupted his ability to phase, also disrupted his ability to interface with tech. But I find that unlikely, though possible.

Comment: Going into the internet, absorbing all of human history, creating "copies" of himself in other robot bodies, etc.: What makes those abilities of an AI?

Comment: @Worse_Username Interfacing with the internet seems like a given. Absorbing (learning) all of human history... Like a computer? And creating "copies" of himself was more a direct ability of Ultron, but even this ability has been seen in plenty of other media by AI.

Comment: An AI is still a program, it does not necessarily have the ability to work the computer. @JunKang

Comment: Sure, but it's a typical ability seen in AI in fictional stories. We're not talking about in real life. Do you really think Ultron was just a "program"?

Comment: "abilities typical of an AI in media" does not "abilities of an AI" make.

Answer (score 2):

At the stage when Ultron was attempted to get the missile codes it was not Vision that was stopping him it was JARVIS. JARVIS only becomes The Vision afterwards when he is uploaded to the synthetic body Ultron had created and imbued with The Mind Stone. There are then a few lines of dialogue that reinforce The Vision is not JARVIS:

> **Tony Stark**: We...we reconfigured JARVIS' matrix to create something new.
>
> **Steve Rogers**: I think I've had my fill of new.
>
> **Vision**: You think I'm a child of Ultron?
>
> **Steve Rogers**: You're not?
>
> **Vision**: I'm not Ultron. I'm not JARVIS. I am...I am.

This means that although like Ultron, The Vision is born of both a child of an AI and The Mind Stone, he has not been shown to have any "AI type capabilities".

Comment: That doesn't take into consideration what he did to Ultron towards the end of the movie. He "hacked" Ultron and locked him out of the internet, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ah sorry, I got misunderstood the scene you were talking about and forgot about the end. This is more of a theory than anything but perhaps because The Vision physically has to touch Ultron to burn him out of the internet rather than some kind of remote lock it is more of a Mind Stone power than AI, though the visuals and sounds used certainly are more reminiscent of previous JARVIS scenes.

Comment: Also, given the fact that Ultron created Vision so that he could transfer himself into Vision's body, I would assume, if he had succeeded, he would still have had all of his abilities. Obviously that's hypothetical, but seems like a safe assumption. I want some evidence, either from the movies or comics, that say whether or not Vision has these abilities.

Comment: @JunKang I think it would be helpful if you added your comment to the original question to clarify. It's obviously implied that the powers were transferred, it would be helpful if you clarified you're looking for examples. In the movies, the examples you gave are clearly the only ones evident.